# User friendly messages in asp web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can you please explain the better approaches to define the messages externally (like xml) instead of directly putting in c# or vb code. Actually,the administrator can configure these user friendly messages of the application. So i would prefer some message key to retrieve the particular message.

Comment: Can frame user friendly messages in database,then fetch accordingly regarding code..the messages can be altered using CMS..

Comment: @Upvote MarkAnswer : Yes, its possible. but it may reduce the performance of the application. Is there any other method to achieve this?

Comment: You want to show user friendly messages for errors or accomplishing tasks..

Comment: @Upvote MarkAnswer : Both

Comment: State the error code and page to navigate in webconfig..No need to worry about many pages.You can accomplish it with single page using query strings

Answer (score 0):

Use ASP.NET resources to store your web page messages. More info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

You can either place your custom messages, having a corresponding message id and refer the required messages in the code using the message id, in the db or in an xml file. Storing it in db will be much preferable.

Comment: Storing it in db is possible,but it may reduce the performance when fetch the message from db.